# Delete domain profiles older than x days

Tags: windows, powershell

i need some help in order to complete the script, i have already script which deleting specific profiles on the remote server, but i want o add time frame. Example: if the profile was not used for more than 120 days delete it.

```
Function Get-OldProfiles {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)] [string]$computerName
)


PROCESS {
    foreach ($computer in $computerName) {
        Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow  "Housekeeping on $computer"
        Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow  "Mapping drive \\$computer\c$"
        $drive = New-PSDrive -Name $computer.replace(".","-") -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\$computer\C$ 
        Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow  "Checking windows version"
        #Cheking windows version
        $version = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).version
        Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow  "Windows version $version"


        #Profile Deleting area.
        if ($version -ge 6) {
            Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow  "Getting profiles from WMI"
            $profiles = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer Win32_UserProfile -filter "LocalPath Like 'C:\\Users\\%'" | Where-object localpath -Match 'B.{5}R$'| Select-Object {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)}
            if ($profiles -ne $null)  {
                $profiles | foreach { 
                Write-host -ForegroundColor Red  ("Deleting profile: " + $_.LocalPath)
                #$_.Delete()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried this:

`$profiles= Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -class Win32_UserProfile -filter "Special = False -and LocalPath Like 'C:\\Users\\%'" | Where-object localpath -Match 'B.{5}R$' | Where {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-120)}`

But it returns an error

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_UserProfile where Special = False -and LocalPath Like 'C:\\Users\\%'"
At line:22 char:24 + $profiles= Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -class Win32_UserPr ...
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are multiple ways to find last time a profile was used. Also, functions and cmdlets should be named `verb-noun`, ex `Get-OldProfile`

Comment: I was trying to add this command before delete() | Where {(!$_.Special) -and ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5))} but i get an error. After google search i faund a lot of various ways but it wont work for me as i have a lack of knowledge of scripting. So am trying to learn by doing simple tasks :)

Comment: Wmi date, eventlog, registry (i think), user folder lastmodified.

Comment: Guys if anybody is watching it :) trying to add `$profiles= Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -class Win32_UserProfile -filter "Special = False -and LocalPath Like 'C:\\Users\\%'" | Where-object localpath -Match 'B.{5}R$' | Where {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-120)}` this way getting error that  `Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_UserProfile where Special = False -
and LocalPath Like 'C:\\Users\\%'"
At line:22 char:24
+             $profiles= Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -class Win32_UserPr ...`

Comment: Thank you Frode F will try to google it.

Comment: Add code to the question, not as a comment

Comment: I think all most succsess :D now the code sayking the true or false  then added this code line :) so basicaly i thinnk it coul be some boolean statement am i right ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `-and` in a WQL-filter, it's just `AND`. Try:

```
$profiles = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_UserProfile -filter "Special = False AND LocalPath Like 'C:\\Users\\%'" |
Where-Object { ($_.localpath -Match 'B.{5}R$') -and ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-120)) }
```

Comment: yes it is working ! thanks. Just checked. you are Awsome :)